# SpringのAutoWiredの挙動について

Tags: java, spring

こんばんは、皆様のお知恵を拝借したくて書き込みます。

```
@Service
public class Parent1 extends Child {
    // ここは定義だけ
}

public class Child extends BaseChild {
    // ここはBaseの呼び出しを行う
}

public class BaseChild {
    public void aMethod() {
        Create c = new Create();
        // c のメソッド呼び出しを行う
    }
}
```

上記の様な構成で、ちょっと失念してしまったのですが
どこかがabstractが入ってた筈なのですが・・・

```
@Component
public class Create {
    @AutoWired
    Properties prop;
}
```

@Autowired対象のSpring設定

```
<bean id="prop" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>/WEB-INF/resources/test.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

BaseChild内の処理で、別クラスCreateをインスタンス化して
メソッドを呼び出しているのですが
インスタンス化したクラスで使おうとしているプロパティの
AutoWiredでの注入が出来ずに困っています。

Parent1の様な構成をしていない単独クラスのParent2で
AutoWiredをするとちゃんと注入されるので
記述等がおかしい可能性は低そうなのですが・・・
Springは経験が少ない為、ご教授お願い致します。

Comment: 多分ですが、 Parent1 や Parent2 には、 @Component アノテーションがついていたのではないでしょうか。

Comment: お返事の方ありがとうございます。
ご指摘の通り。Parent1やParent2のクラスの先頭に
@Serviceアノテーションが付与されていた気がします。

Answer (score 1):

多分なのですが、 Parent2 で意図した動作を行わせた際には、 `@Autowired` で `Create` クラスを注入していたのではないでしょうか。

```
public class Parent2 {
    @Autowired
    Create c;
    public void hogeMethod() {
        // c のメソッド呼び出し
    }
}
```

同様に、`BaseChild`でも、`Create` を `@Autowired` で注入すれば、意図した動作になるはずです。

勝手に値・オブジェクトが注入されるのは、spring によって管理されている bean だけであって、自前で new したオブジェクトの中の `@Autowired` へは、勝手には注入されません。

NOTE: `@Service` が付与されているという情報から推察するに、Parent1 や Parent2 は、 あなたの実行環境では bean として spring で管理されている様子です。

FWIW: 基底クラスの中での Autowired が可能かどうか、試してみた結果 -> https://github.com/Yuki-Inoue/test-mvn-autowired